# Can a PPL holder fly family and friends aboard an A380?

Tags: passenger, regulations, airbus-a380, ppl, pilot-certification

Would I be able to fly an A380 with a private pilots license and carry family and friends? I know I can fly the A380 with a PPL.

Comment: Which country or regulations are you asking about? If it's FAA/USA, we [already have this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/23404/62), although the same general answer probably applies in most places.

Comment: You can - at least as SIC. FAA would allow you to be a PIC of any plane as long as an you passed a checkride with an authorized examiner, even with PPL. However, where I live for example, you cannot do the above in high performance and/or turbine aircrafts or those heavier than a certain weight without ATP license.

Answer (score 11):

Yes. But you will still need instrument rating and ATPL theory as this is multi crew aircraft. The amount of learning will be the same as to get CPL. Maybe fees for the license will be lower but who cares if you buy an A380?

Comment: Why instrument and ATPL are necessary? Can't you fly any aircraft (in the US for example) as SIC in VFR conditions after just being type rated?

Comment: In the US you do not need an ATP to hold a type rating. Private/Instrument/Multi is all that is required. As a private pilot, you can get a type rating in any jet and then fly it legally after meeting the requirements of 61.64.

Comment: @Richard I'm saying the same thing

Comment: I don't say that you need ATP but in Europe you will have to pass ATPL exams if you want to get IR with ME to be eligible to get TR. MCC will be also required.

Comment: @PIXP Sorry - I saw the SIC in VFR in your comment. A Private Pilot with a type rating could fly IMC as PIC, but he MUST (in the US) have an instrument rating and a multi-engine rating to get a type rating. So I was answering your questions as to why and instrument and ATPL were necessary.